# How to modify this sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have a sequence that is

$$
\alpha_n = 
\begin{cases}
a \alpha_{n-1} + \alpha_{n-2}, \text{if $n$ is even} \\
b \alpha_{n-1} + \alpha_{n-2}, \text{if $n$ is odd} 
\end{cases}.
$$
The initial conditions $\alpha_{0} = 0$ and $\alpha_{1}=1$. The sequence $\alpha_{n}$ satisfies the following identity

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{m} \left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\xi(k+1)} \alpha_k ^2 = \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)\alpha_m \alpha_{m+1},
$$
where $\xi(n)=0$ for $n$ is even and $\xi(n)=1$ for $n$ is odd and $\alpha_m$ is just a sequence which takes unique values. I just want to obtain the sum that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{m} \alpha_k ^2 . 
$$
How can I remove the expression $\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)^{\xi(k+1)}$ from the left hand side summation and then put to the right hand side.

Best regards.

Comment: It looks to me like you can show that $\alpha_k + b \alpha_{k+1} = \alpha_{k+2}$, just by directly examining $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \beta_k$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \beta_{k+1}$, where $\beta_k = (\frac{b}{a})^{\xi(k+1)}.$

Comment: Dear @Chris, 
I have added some new informations about the sequence. The sequence  can be change according to $n$.

Comment: I can derive explicit formulea for $\alpha_{2n}$ and $\alpha_{2n+1}$ ... but $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \alpha_{k}^{2}$ is not so nice ... do you want the formulea for the $\alpha$'s ?

Comment: I added the formula for $\alpha$ @DonaldSplutterwit.